# Repository don't return value from my Test Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, unit-of-work

I'm new in Unit Test and i'm trying to write a unit test for the below method of my service:

```
public InventoryViewModel GetInventory(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, long roomServiceId)
{
    InventoryViewModel inv = new InventoryViewModel();
    var roomService = _unitOfWork.RoomServiceRepository.GetByID(roomServiceId);
    if (roomService == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("there is not the roomService");
        ....
    }
...
}
```

this method works correctly, but when i call this method from my `TestMethod`, `RoomServiceRepository` doesn't return the roomService. My testMethod looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class InventoryTest
{
    private UnityContainer _container;
    readonly MockObjectsSetup _mos = new MockObjectsSetup();
    private IInventoryService _inventoryService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _mos.Setup(_container);
        Config.UnityTestConfig.RegisterTypes(_container);
        _container.RegisterType<IInventoryService, InventoryService>();
        _inventoryService = (InventoryService)_container.Resolve(typeof(InventoryService));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Dont_Change_NotSelected_PriceValues()
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("6/21/2016");
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2016");

        long roomServiceId = 17;
        InventoryViewModel invViewModel = new InventoryViewModel();

        invViewModel.isUpdatingBoardPrice = invViewModel.isUpdatingPrice = invViewModel.isUpdatingFloatAvailability = true;
        invViewModel.isUpdatingCertainAvailability = false;
        invViewModel.StartDate = startDate;
        invViewModel.EndDate = endDate;
        invViewModel.RoomServiceId = roomServiceId;
        invViewModel.CertainAvailability = 0;
        invViewModel.FloatAvailability = 8;

        var inv = _inventoryService.GetInventory(startDate, endDate, roomServiceId);

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you mocked your `inventoryService` and do you get any exception?

Comment: i haven't mocked it, as I told, I'm new and i don't know how to mock the service.

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop relying on DI and IOC in your tests and start using mocks.

Something like RhinoMocks for example but there are other frameworks as well.

The idea is that you prepare your services, you mock them to return data that would normally come from a database for example, then you run some functionality, call the method you want to test and assert what happens with the result.

Effectively you're saying you don't care where the data is coming from but it needs to have a controlled response and that's what you are mocking. You only care about functionality. Does that make sense?